# Modal dentro de tabela - Mysql

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando passar informações que estão dentro de uma tabela para um modal.
Atualmente o que tenho é uma função simples que exibe na tela um link e ao clicar nela, abre outra página com uma imagem QR.
Queria deixar isso mais dinâmico e fazer com que se abra em um modal.

Fiz algumas tentativas, e vi bastante coisa no Tec. Google, mas não consegui adaptar para meu código. Se puderem me dar essa ajuda, agradeço demais!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Código atual:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive text-center">
      <table class="table table-hover table-dark" id="alist">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col"><?php echo $lang['WALLET_ADDRESS']; ?></th>
        <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 30px"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach ($addressList as $address)
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$address."</td>";?>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $server_url;?>qrgen/?address=<?php echo $address;?>">
          <img src="<?php echo $server_url;?>qrgen/?address=<?php echo $address;?>" alt="QR Code" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;"></td></tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Imagem do Código atual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tentativa:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive text-center">
      <table class="table table-hover table-dark" id="alist">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col"><?php echo $lang['WALLET_ADDRESS']; ?></th>
        <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 30px"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach ($addressList as $address)
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$address."</td>";?>
        <td>
          <a href="<?php echo $server_url;?>qrgen/?address=<?php echo $address;?>" class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qrcode_modal"><i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 30px;color:white;border:0;"></i></a></td></tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
                  <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="qrcode_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 20px"></i>QRCODE</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img src="<?php echo $server_url;?>qrgen/?address=<?php echo $address;?>" style="width: 120px">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Na minha tentativa o modal exibe apenas a informação de 1 dado, o foreach não funciona, ou seja, independente da linha que eu clique para exibição, sempre vai mostrar apenas o QR referente a 1 endereço.

Imagem da minha tentativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: da uma olhada nisso aqui. é o que eu mais uso: https://jquerymodal.com/

Comment: O modal em si está funcionando, atualizei algumas informações e fotos a respeito do que está acontecendo.

Answer (score -1):

Não manjo muito mas utilizo alguns modais de forma parecida, vou tentar explicar para ajudar...

Primeiramente no modal, vamos tirar a imagem do qrcode e colocar uma div com id="qrcode", para que possamos alterar o conteúdo com a imagem correta:

```html
<!-- Modal qrcode -->
<div class="modal fade" id="qrcode_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 20px"></i>QRCODE</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="qrcode" class="container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agora vamos colocar um evento de click em cada link para chamar uma função que substituirá o conteúdo na div id="qrcode" e mostrará o modal. Exemplo de item dentro do seu foreach:

```html
<a onclick="mostrarQRCODE('dados-para-gerar-qrcode');">
    <i class="fas fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 30px;color:white;border:0;">Nome do Item</i>
</a>
```

Agora, a função javascript que receberá o endereço passado ao clicar no item, fará a substituição na div id="qrcode" e mostrará o modal usando jquery:

```html
function mostrarQRCODE(gerarQRCODE){
  $.post("gerar-qrcode.php", { 'qrcode':gerarQRCODE},
      function (resposta) {
          // Subistitui o conteúdo da div com id="qrcode"
          $("#qrcode").html(resposta);
          // Mostra o modal usando jquery
          $('#qrcode_modal').modal('show');
      }
  );
}
```

Página php para gerar o qrcode:

```php
// Recebe dados para gerar o qrcode
$qrcode = (isset($_POST['qrcode'])) ? $_POST['qrcode'] : null;

// Função para gerar o qrcode
...
...
...

// Retorno do qrcode, para ser mostrado dentro da div id=qrcode
echo $qrcode;
```

Bom, a lógica que eu uso aqui é essa, não consegui testar no seu exemplo, porém, se precisar, vai ser de algumas pequenas adaptações.

Comment: Não deu certo aqui. As imagens dos QR's são geradas automaticamente dentro da função: "<?php echo $server_url;?>qrgen/?address=<?php echo $address;?>", na minha tentativa a imagem é exibida, porém gera a mesma imagem para todas as linhas, ou seja, gera ,por exemplo somente para a linha 1 e replica essa informação nas demais linhas.

Comment: Fica um pouco difícil de ficar entendendo esse tanto de abertura e fechamento de tags, bem como o que cada coisa faz, por isso passei de uma forma genérica, assim você pode adaptar para o seu caso, mas enfim, você pode gerar essas imagens na hora usando o ajax do jQuery, fica bem fácil de implementar usando esse mesmo exemplo que passei, vou editar aqui para você ter uma noção melhor. :)