# como resolver o problema do modal pegando o ultimo id

Tags: html, laravel, api

```
          <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table table-striped task-table">
                  <thead>

                      <th class="col-sm-1">Sistema</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-1">Usuario</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-1">Label</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-2">Descrição</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-1">Atualizar</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-2">Data Cadastro</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-1">Situação</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-2">Ações</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      @if (count($versoes) > 0)
                          @foreach ($versoes as $versao)
                              <tr>
                                  <td>{{ $versao->sistema->descricao }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $versao->usuario->usuario}}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $versao->label }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $versao->descricao }}</td>
                                  <td>@if($versao->atualiza_db==0){{{'Não'}}}@else{{{'Sim'}}}@endif</td>
                                  <td>{{ $versao->data_versao }}</td>
                                  <td>@if($versao->situacao==0){{{'Inativo'}}}
                                      @elseif($versao->situacao==1){{{'Ativa Para Atualização'}}}
                                      @elseif($versao->situacao==2){{{'Em Desenvolvimento'}}}
                                      @elseif($versao->situacao==3){{{'Aguardando Teste'}}}
                                      @endif
                                    </td>

                                  <td>
                                  <form action="{{ route('v1.versoes.delete', $versao->id) }}" method="post">
                                  {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                  {!! method_field('delete') !!}
                                   <a rel="tooltip" href="{{ route('v1.versoes.editar', $versao->id) }}" data-original-title="Editar" title="Editar" style="float: right;
                                        margin-top: -2px;
                                        margin-right:30px;">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
                                    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                  </a>
                                  <a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Subir" title="Upload da Versão" style="float: right;
                                        margin-top: -2px;
                                        margin-right:5px;" data-id="{{ $versao->id }}" class="botao"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    <i class="fas fa-folder-plus fa-2x"></i>
                                    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                  </a>

                                  <button type="submit" data-original-title="Excluir" title="Excluir">
                                      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                      <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                  </button>
                              </form>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          @endforeach
                      @else
                          <tr><td colspan="7">Nenhum evento encontrado.</td></tr>
                      @endif
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" {{$versao->id}} role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload da Versão</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          {{$versao->id}}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e elaborar um [mcve]. Da maneira que está é impossível aferir qualquer coisa sobre o problema, até porque a pergunta consiste apenas de um código HTML aleatório.

Comment: é porque criei o modal só que coloquei ele fora do laço ele pega o ultimo e se colocar dentro do laço pega o primeiro

Comment: Mas nem tem laço na sua pergunta :(

Comment: é pq iria ficar grande de mais o código

Comment: E é por isso que sempre solicitamos um [mcve], não o código completo.

Comment: editei lá, no php puro já usei modal mais com o laravel ta sendo a primeira vez

Comment: Acho que documentação do [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) pode te ajudar, você vai precisar trabalhar nos eventos que o componente modal dispara.

Comment: Seria importante tu elaborar a tua pergunta, não sei exatamente onde esta o seu problema, e o que tu pretende fazer. Somente o codigo não me ajudara a entender a sua situação.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta aqui:

[Exemplo 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/413152/exibir-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-modal-com-foreach/413303#413303)

[Exemplo 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412302/modal-dentro-de-tabela-mysql/412721#412721)

Vamos ver se agora rola um feedback

HehehehE